# Just had my windshield tinted by a shop, will little bubbles go away?

Tags: tint

I just had my windows tinted.
The shop said that it takes a few days for the tint to settle based on weather, temperature, etc.

After driving I noticed little bubbles/aberrations on the bottom of the windshield (near the hood).
Is this normal? Will this go away? My gut feel says no.

Should I take it back to the shop? Is it easy to fix?

Comment: You realize window tint on the windshield is limited to the top 4" in California?

Comment: Yes. Unless you have a medical reason. I got my dermatologist to write me a doctor’s note.

Comment: If the shop said "it takes a few days" then I'd wait a bit and see.  If the issue doesn't resolve then take it back and have them correct it.

Comment: I tinted my own house windows last year - the bubbles are still there.  Give it a few days & if no better, then go back & make them do it properly.